How do I fix the ValueError encountered in my vary_temperature function?
So  i am trying to replicate a simple autocomplete model based on the article below
https://jaketae.github.io/study/auto-complete/
When i run my final function, i am running into a value error. It says my model is expecting 1 input while recieving a 60 input vector. I have tried chaning the paramaters but I am not sure how to change the dimension of the input that is received by my model.

